# MySQL library's in C++ using cmake

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake

**here is the cmakelists.txt file that I use to generate build system using CMAKE GUI on windows (cause I actually have to make console application in c++ for windows).**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16) # Or whatever version you use
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
# THIS HAS TO COME BEFORE THE PROJECT LINE
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
# THIS HAS TO COME BEFORE THE PROJECT LINE
project(test VERSION 0.0.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)
project(main)
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0")
add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test mysqlcppconn)
target_compile_features(test PRIVATE cxx_range_for)  
set(STDFS_LIB stdc++fs)
```

**and here is the code I am trying to run (main.cpp) -**

```
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>


int main()
{
 return 0;
}
```

**I am getting error on make #include <cppconn/driver.h> - no such file or folder.**

I am guessing this

set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0")

could be set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "C:/mysqlconn")

but it does not work anyway if I put MySQL Connector C++ 8.0 libraries there, so what should be done about this? using mysql connector in c++ in 2021 should not be secret, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the path to the include directories and I would think that linking will also not work, because you are not adding the necessary paths as well.

If `FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR` is your correct path, then it would look like this:

```
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib64)
```

Comment: those mysql .h files are stored in c:\mysqlconnector\include\jdbc\cppconn   so set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "c:\mysqlconnector") include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/includepath) link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/librarypath) ????

Comment: Obviously you have to set it to the correct values of your system, whatever they are.

Comment: so what is /includepath ? is it from the set(); ?

Comment: Hmm I'm working on small video for You -cppconn/driver.h is in c:\mysqlconnector\include\jdbc\cppconn folder, but it still does not work with Your answer, driver.h can't be found....

Comment: https://filebin.net/s44lp34yldlebvvh/howitlooks.mp4?t=y8vq3y7f